# geojson Leaflet pop-up will not appear or breaks marker

Tags: maps, leaflet, geojson

I have geoJson data I am displaying using Leaflet. The markers appear on the map as they are supposed to but I cannot bind a popup to it. If I append it to the marker directly, nothing will appear. If I append it to the layer, it just doesn't appear but the marker does. Please take a look and advise what the problem is!

```
function playgroundMarker(feature, layer){
    var popupOptions = {width: 200};
    var popupContent = "This is some content";


    var marker = new L.icon({iconUrl: "lib/leaflet/images/play_icon.png"});
    //L.marker.bindPopup(popupContent, popupOptions); - This breaks it
    //layer.bindPopup(popupContent, popupOptions); - This just doesn't appear
    layer.setIcon(marker);

};  
var playground = L.geoJson(playgrounds, {
    onEachFeature: playgroundMarker
}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you [just `.bindPopup()`](https://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/wutez/edit?html,output), nothing appears. This is expected.

If you [`.bindPopup()` **and then** `.openPopup()`](https://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/kix/edit?html,output), the popup will show.

The main problem you have there is the call to `setIcon`. [`setIcon` expects its only argument to be an instance of `L.Icon`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#marker-seticon), **not** an instance of `L.Marker`. The marker is already the `layer` received by the `onEachFeature` callback.

You do not need to (and should not) create markers in `onEachFeature`. Markers are created in the [`pointToLayer` callback option of `L.GeoJSON`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#geojson-pointtolayer). If you need to create markers, override the default `pointToLayer` callback and do it there.

When you use GeoJSON, the `pointToLayer` and `style` options work their magic to convert points into `L.Marker`s (`pointToLayer`), and LineStrings/Polygons into `L.Polyline`s/`L.Polygon`s. Once all GeoJSON features have been converted to *either* a marker or a polyline/polygon, *then* `onEachFeature` iterates through all. It's easy to mix these up.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about something - are you suggesting using pointToLayer instead of onEachFeature or using them both? Thank you for the response btw

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand you right, but if you have geojson objects you can use the pointToLayer function to add an Marker. The eachFeature function is good for binding a popup.

```
var playground = L.geoJson(playgrounds, {
     pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
         return L.marker(latlng, {icon: new L.icon({iconUrl: "lib/leaflet/images/play_icon.png"})});
     },
    onEachFeature: playgroundMarker
}).addTo(map);



function playgroundMarker(feature, layer) {
            var popup = new L.Popup({
                autoPan: false,
                keepInView: true,
                closeButton: false,
                offset: new L.point(0, -5)
            }).setContent("This is some content");


        layer.bindPopup(popup);
        //you can also choose the click event oder simply no event and add layer.openPopup();
        layer.on({
            mouseover: function () {
                layer.openPopup();
            },
            mouseout: function () {
                layer.closePopup()
            },
            mousemove: function (e) {
                popup.setLatLng(e.latlng);
            }
        });
    }
```